# Which tense the conditional 1,2 exactly indicate?

Tags: tense, conditional-constructions

As I far as I know the conditional 1 and 2 indicate only probability.

For example,

> If I see him tomorrow, I will tell him. *Indicates high probability to
>   see him.*
>
> or If I saw him tomorrow, I would tell him. *Indicates less
>   probability.*

*But what is the tense here exactly?*

> Can I say If I see him *now*, I will tell him 
>   or If i see him *now*, I would tell him?

My question is based on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-Np7dmvw0U&t=282s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my ear, the tense is ungrammatical here, unless you're speaking of a *hypothetical* situation:

> If I **saw** him **tomorrow**, I would tell him.

And depending on the contextual meaning of **now**, this might be idiomatic or it might not:

> If I **see** him **now**, I will tell him.

*If I see him **at this very moment**, I will tell him.* <sup>no</sup>

We could concoct a scenario where that would be idiomatic, but it would be very contrived. It would be on the order of:

> If I'm thinking of the ace of spades, I will tell him. Am I thinking of the ace of spades?

Who doesn't know what they're seeing or thinking at a particular moment? It's more of a guessing game than a conditional.

*Now that I know that important bit of information, if I see him, I will tell him.*<sup>yes</sup>

Comment: What is the wrong with If I see him at this very moment, I will tell him?

Comment: @Gamal Thomas: There is nothing grammatically wrong with it, and as I said, we could concoct a scenario where it would make sense on a semantic level.  But why use examples that are questionable?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. There is nothing intrinsically future about those conditionals. They are only specified as non-past.

Comment: Are you saying *If I see him now, I would tell him* is grammatical?

Comment: Sorry, I misread part of your question. No, it would have to be _If I saw him now, I would tell him_.